# Is it posible get a bool (true or false) to know if a row exists?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know if in a table there are a row that a field is true.

- MyTable(ID, MyBool...)

Really I don't want to get the rows, only if exists at least one that is true.

I have tried this query:

```
select ID from Mytable where Exists(select * from MyTable where MyBool = 1);
```

But I get all the row which field is true. I think that this uses more resources that I need. So I am looking somthing like that:

```
if Exists(select * from MyTablewhere ID = 1
    and MyBool= 1)
    return 1;
```

But I get an error that I can not return a value in this context.

So, is there any way to know with a true or false if there are rows that is true?

thank so much.

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected output

Comment: What is the context where you want to know?  What needs to know... just you?  Or some other part of your application?  Where is this logic going to be used?  Without that context I cannot answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just skip `FROM Mytable`:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable WHERE MyBool = 1)
```

The above query will return a single row (`1`) if there is at least one record in `MyTable` where `MyBool = 1`. It will no rows at all if no such record exists.

Answer (score 2):

not a bool but will tell you yes or no

```
select count(*) from MyTable where MyBool = 1
```

bool

```
select case when count(*) > 1 then 1 else 0 end
  from MyTable where MyBool = 1
```

if you don't need a false

```
select top 1 1 
  from MyTable where MyBool = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but the in this case I would like to avoid the count(*) because it has not the efficience that I am looking for. I appreciate your idea.
Giorgos' solution is what I wanted.

Comment: OK Giorgos does not return true or false. "know with a true or false"

Comment: And if you are looking for efficiency then select top 1 1 is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

select top 1 ID from MyTable where MyBool = 1